# date is being displayed as datetime in sql server using JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to figure out why date is being displayed as datetime after trying hard posting here.
I am using sql server and I am using spring boot jpa to create the fields,the server is running for few years without any issue,I am trying to add a new field and it is being displayed as datetime instead of date in the database.

Please find my code below:
In Java class

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")

private Date mydate;
```

In pom.xml

```
<dependencies>

<dependency>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>

<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>

<artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>

<scope>provided</scope>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

</dependency>

<!-- <dependency>

<groupId>org.mockito</groupId>

<artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>

<version>1.10.19</version>

</dependency> -->

<!-- <dependency>

<groupId>mysql</groupId>

<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

</dependency> -->

<dependency>

<groupId>org.json</groupId>

<artifactId>json</artifactId>

<version>20090211</version>

</dependency>

<!-- <dependency>

<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>

<version>5.0.0.M1</version>

</dependency> -->

<dependency>

<groupId>javax.validation</groupId>

<artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>

<version>1.1.0.Final</version>

</dependency>

<!-- cache -->

<!-- <dependency>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>

</dependency> -->

<dependency>

<groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>

<artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>

<version>2.2.3-1</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>

<artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>

<version>6.1.0.jre8</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>

<artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>

<version>4.0</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>javax.activation</groupId>

<artifactId>activation</artifactId>

<version>1.1</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>

<!-- <exclusions>

<exclusion>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>

</exclusion>

</exclusions> -->

</dependency>

<!-- <dependency>

<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>

</dependency> -->

<dependency>

<groupId>joda-time</groupId>

<artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>

<version>2.9.9</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>

<artifactId>poi</artifactId>

<version>3.17-beta1</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>

<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>

<version>3.17-beta1</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

<groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>

<artifactId>guava</artifactId>

<version>23.6-jre</version>

</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `mydate` column in your database table?

Comment: mydate datatype is datetime

Comment: If database type is datetime then it must be shown as datetime. Explain your problem in more details.

Comment: You need to change your datatype to `date` if you want it to hold only date and not datetime. You can change the type by doing something like

`ALTER TABLE [table_name] ALTER COLUMN mydate date;`